# Has anyone installed OPA (open policy agent) Docker Container in Azure App Services?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, open-policy-agent

Has anyone installed 'openpolicyagent/opa' as a docker image deployment in Azure App Service successfully?  If yes can you please share how you did this?  I attempted to do this with the startup command 'docker run -it --rm -p 8181:8181 openpolicyagent/opa run --server --addr :8181' and without a startup command.

Both effectively produce the same error which is the site fails to start...

/home/LogFiles/2022_03_10_pl0sdlwk00001X_docker.log
2022-03-10T22:39:28.658Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 0 Seconds
2022-03-10T22:39:28.668Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2022-03-10T22:39:28.669Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 80:80 --name opa-policy-server_0_51a5bbcf -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=opa-policy-server -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME= -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=f6284c65c14198cd70b55d3c9c413d8fa5047ec06e41a24daf1e4ba58ad6479f openpolicyagent/opa:latest

2022-03-10T22:39:28.670Z INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2022-03-10T22:39:31.463Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container dd-opa-policy-server_0_51a5bbcf for site opa-policy-server
2022-03-10T22:39:31.477Z ERROR - Container dd-opa-policy-server_0_51a5bbcf for site opa-policy-server has exited, failing site start
2022-03-10T22:39:31.483Z ERROR - Container dd-opa-policy-server_0_51a5bbcf didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2022-03-10T22:39:31.487Z INFO  - Stopping site opa-policy-server because it failed during startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the App Service, in the Docker tab, use the following settings:

- Image and tag: openpolicyagent/opa
- Startup command: run --server --addr:80

[image]

If you want to use a port different than the default port 80, lets say 8181, make sure to add this application setting:

```
WEBSITES_PORT: 8181
```

Comment: Thank you that worked.  Evidently including docker before run gave it some issues.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: I also host my Open Policy Agent centrally as container in Azure. Is there a way to include an existing Styra configuration file "--config-file=./conf.yaml"? If I use my Open Policy Agent as executable (Windows), this works at the initial start of the Agent as server.